# Entity Framework 4.1 DbContext Extending Partial Classes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Building a C# application using EF 4.1 with Database First. My question centers around using extension methods to return values through the DbContext object.

My entities were created as partial classes by the DbContext generator. I have a **Projects** table and a related **Managers** table and through the context object I can perform LINQ queries and access projects and the assigned project manager. If the **Manager** table has firstname and lastname fields how would I write my extension as a property or method to concatenate the first and last name fields so that when I query for a project and use the manager relation the property *FullName* returns the combined value?

This example has a variable _*projects* populated with a list of Projects created using LINQ query:

```
Fields["manager"].Value = _projects[i].Project.ProjectManager.FullName
```

I can makethe *FullName* property into a method and pass the id for the manager however wouldn't that make it into an additional query? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you're always going to be accessing the `ProjectManager` navigation property, you can include it in the initial query by using the `Include` method

```
var projects = (from p in ctx.Projects
                select p)
                   .Include(p => p.ProjectManager)
                   .ToList();
```

Then you can add the following property to your `Manager` class (in a seperate file than the generated one)

```
public string FullName
{
    get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
}
```

And access it using

```
var manager = projects[0].ProjectManager.FullName;
```

If I missinterpreted your question, could you provide an example of what your code would look like using your proposed extension method?

Comment: Thanks Brice for the answer. I now realize that the first and last name are available because I am extending the Manager partial class. The property you wrote is spot on.